# The correct way of extending an ArrayList and and implementing an interface using Generics

Tags: java, generics, interface

I need to implement an interface that has two generic type arguments and a method that takes one generic type as the argument and the other generic type as a return type. This is how I implemented it but I don't know if it's the right way.

```
public interface Evaluate<K, T> 
{
      T use(K k); 

}
```

Also, I need to extend the Java's ArrayList and add methods to it such as map. The map() method needs to take one argument of type Evaluate and return a new list. I don't know if I should implement the interface and how to actually pass the argument in my method. This is my attempt so far:

```
public class Array<K, T> extends java.util.ArrayList<T> implements Evaluate<K,T>
{
    public ArrayList<T> map(Evaluate f1)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Your interface is called Evaluate and you are implementing and taking Function. What is Evaluate for and what is Function ?

Comment: At a glance your code looks ok, what is the actual problem you are having?

Comment: I edited the code as I had a mistake

Comment: Your interface implementation is still wrong.

Comment: You can fix one more thing. If you are extending Evaluate interface you don't need to pass Evaluate instance inside map (Array class can simply use its own). If you want to pass it, interface implementation is not needed.

Comment: It is giving me three errors: The serializable class Array does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long, Multiple markers at this line
 - Evaluate is a raw type. References to generic type Evaluate<K,T> should be 
  parameterized
 - ArrayList cannot be resolved to a type

Answer (score 0):

Do it either:

```
public class Array<K, T> extends java.util.ArrayList<T> implements Evaluate<K,T> {
    T use(K k) {
        // implementation
    }

    public java.util.ArrayList<T> map() {
        // use(K) somewhere here
    }
}
```

or

```
public class Array<K, T> extends java.util.ArrayList<T> {
    public java.util.ArrayList<T> map(Evaluate<K,T> evaluate) {
        // use evaluate somewhere here
    }
}
```

Your implementation does't have definition of `T use(K)` declared in interface - you can leave it unimplemented only in an abstract class or an interface extending another one. Also your argument is raw since you didn't write it like `map(Evaluate<K,T> f1)` (Java doesn't automatically substitute generic parameters).

Comment: What do you mean by: "Your implementation does't have definition of T use(K) declared in interface" ? A method in an interface shouldn't be left with an empty body? Also, why it is giving me the error: ArrayList cannot be resolved to a type?

Comment: You wrote `implements Evaluate<K,T>` and your `Array` class isn't abstract. That means that in `Array` class has to be some `T use(K k)` implementation or the file just won't compile. Interface has to have only declarations, its not-abstract implementations have to have them. I've added missing `java.util.`, but, honestly, when I see someone struggling with such simple compiler's errors I wonder if he should already jump into slightly more advanced stuff like writing own generics class.